# Cannot create unknown type 'Style' Exception in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this code to create dynamic button style based on generated points from another class which generates on runtime and i have this exception 
'Cannot create unknown type 'Style'.' Line number '1' and line position '2'.

```
string s = "<Style xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" x:Key=\"Mystyle\" TargetType=\"Button\">" +
        "<Setter Property=\"Template\">" +
            "<Setter.Value>" +
              "  <ControlTemplate TargetType=\"{x:Type Button}\">" +
                   " <Grid >" +
                           " <Polygon  Points=\""+points+" Fill=\"{TemplateBinding Background}\"" +
                         "Stroke=\"{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}\" DataContext=\"{Binding}\" />" +
                       " <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment=\"Center\"" +
                                   "   VerticalAlignment=\"Center\"/>" +
                   " </Grid>" +
              "  </ControlTemplate>" +
           " </Setter.Value>" +
    "    </Setter>" +
   " </Style>";
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(s);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        Style  readerLoadButton = (Style)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding namespace info......